# Time zone not changing for JSF p:clock

Tags: jsf, timezone, clock

I am trying to change the timezone to be displayed for the `p:clock` element in JSF. Following is the code I am writing:

```
<p:clock pattern="#{sessionScope.dateFormat} #{sessionScope.timeFormat}" mode="server" >
    <f:convertDateTime timeZone="PST" />
</p:clock>
```

But this code remains uneffected irrespective of whatever timezone we are specifying.

Comment: actually, mode server or not does not make any difference for me. I wonder if this component actually works